# Trace/breakpoint trap if I free a pointer, but the same thing does not happen in the other if statements

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, stack

I have this code (I am putting the most important parts):

```
struct card{
    char face[3];
    char suit[4];
};
typedef struct card Card;

struct stack{
    Card cardd;
    struct stack *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct stack Stack;

// prototypes:
void fill_deck(Card *deck);
void randomize_deck(Card *deck);
void make_stacks(Card *deck, Stack *stacks);
void additem(Card card, Stack **stack);
void print_stacks(Stack *stacks, Stack *basestacks);
int move_card(Stack *stacks, Stack *basestacks, unsigned int pos1, unsigned int pos2, unsigned int action);

int main(){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    Card deck[52];
    fill_deck(deck);
    randomize_deck(deck);
    Stack *stacks = calloc(10,sizeof(Stack));
    make_stacks(deck,stacks);
    Stack *basestacks = calloc(4,sizeof(Stack));
    for(size_t i=0;i<4;++i){
        basestacks[i].nextPtr = &(basestacks[i]);
    }
    unsigned int choice;
    unsigned int pos1;
    unsigned int pos2;
    do{
        print_stacks(stacks, basestacks);
        printf("\n\nMoves available:\n");
        printf("1: Moves card from a game stack to another game stack.\n");
        printf("2: Moves card from a game stack to a base stack.\n");
        printf("3: Moves card from a base stack to a game stack.\n\n");
        printf("Insert move: ");
        scanf("%u",&choice);
        if (choice==1){
            /*
            some if for other choices
            */
        }else if (choice==3){
            printf("\nInsert starting stack: ");
            scanf("%u",&pos1);
            printf("\nInsert arrival stack: ");
            scanf("%u",&pos2);
        }
    } while (choice!=0);
}

int move_card(Stack *stacks, Stack *basestacks, unsigned int pos1, unsigned int pos2, unsigned int action){
    --pos1;
    --pos2;
    unsigned int counter_elem = 0;
    if(action==1){
    /*
    some if for other actions
    */
    } else if (action==3){
        Stack *prevfromPtr;
        Stack *fromPtr = &(basestacks[pos1]); 
        Stack *toPtr = &(stacks[pos2]); 
        while(fromPtr->nextPtr!=NULL){
            prevfromPtr = fromPtr;
            fromPtr = fromPtr->nextPtr;
            ++counter_elem;
        }
        Stack *newmovingcard = calloc(1,sizeof(Stack));
        newmovingcard->cardd = fromPtr->cardd;
        newmovingcard->nextPtr = NULL; 
        if (toPtr->nextPtr!=toPtr){
            while(toPtr->nextPtr!=NULL){ 
                toPtr = toPtr->nextPtr;
            }
            toPtr->nextPtr = newmovingcard;
            free(fromPtr);                      // bug breakpoint here
            if (counter_elem!=0){
                prevfromPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
            } else {
                basestacks[pos1].nextPtr = &(basestacks[pos1]);
            }
            return 0;
        } else { 
            toPtr->cardd = newmovingcard->cardd;
            toPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
            free(fromPtr);
            if (counter_elem!=0){
                prevfromPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
            } else {
                basestacks[pos1].nextPtr = &(basestacks[pos1]);
            }
            return 0;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

if you scroll down to `move_card` function, you'll se a comment in the `free(fromPtr)` line. There is the bug that I can't fix. The thing is that in the `move_card` function I have 3 `if` that do certain things (I've only put the third one), and in the first two `if` I do the same thing (`free(fromPtr)`) and there work. I don't know why it doesn't work in the third `if`.

Here is the complete code (the comments and the printf are in italian, I'm sorry): https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2g2
To reproduce enter 3, and then enter the base stack starting card, and then the arrival game stack.

**EDIT:
If I delete the line free(fromPtr), it works. But I don't get why.... Shouldn't I free that pointer??**

Comment: You can only free a pointer that was returned from `malloc()`. A pointer to the middle of an array can't be the pointer that was allocated.

Comment: You can't free part of an array. The entire `basestacks` array can be freed when you're all done.

Comment: @Barmar So how to free all the remaining nodes? If I type free(basestacks) I am only freeing the first 10 nodes of each stack. How can I free the nodes linked to these 10 first nodes? That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your design makes this difficult, because you're mixing an array of Stack with dynamically-linked lists of Stack, and sometimes the `next` pointer points to a newly allocated object, other times it points to an element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You just copy the adress here : `Stack *fromPtr = &(basestacks[pos1]);`

You don't need to free then ^^

You free only things you allocate with malloc or calloc